# I cant log onto any site including email that requires a username and password

Tags: windows-7

My computer got a virus in it which i managed to remove but I am having this problem. My TCP/IP protocol controller is not working properly it says. I have tried to reset but it is not resetting. It says the requested operation requires elevation.
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please take the time to improve your question. See our [How to Ask](http://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask) and the [Rubber Duck Problem Solving](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html) instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Try to login as administrator to resolve the elevation issue but if the network controller is not working then I suggest trying to re-install the driver. Make sure you have another network card to get driver. Or there is a issue with the router. Area you getting an IP address on the interface when you run ipconfig.